# Bootstrap variables correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation, bootstrap

I wrote this R function in order to test between matrix (mat1, mat2) correlation by re-sampling the second matrix numR times to obtain correlation coefficient distribution against which to test the observed value. But irrespective of the observed value I always get the distribution with SD 0.3 max. I don`t see how if the original correlation is as high as 0.9 that after 10000 re-samples it still cannot exceed 0.3. Any comments on the code or a possible test with independent data?

```
resamplerSimAlt <- function(mat1, mat2, numR, graph = FALSE)
{
  statSim <- numeric(numR)
  mat1vcv <- cov(mat1)
  mat2vcvT <- cov(mat2)
  ltM1 <- mat1vcv[col(mat1vcv) <= row(mat1vcv)]
  ltM2T <- mat2vcvT[col(mat2vcvT) <= row(mat2vcvT)]
  statObs <- cor(ltM1, ltM2T)                           
  indice <- c(1:length(mat2))
  resamplesIndices <- lapply(1:numR, function(i) sample(indice, replace = F))
  for (i in 1:numR)
  {
    ss <- mat2[sample(resamplesIndices[[i]])]
    ss <- matrix(ss, nrow = dim(mat2)[[1]], ncol = dim(mat2)[[2]])
    mat2ss <- cov(ss)
    ltM2ss <- mat2ss[col(mat2ss) <= row(mat2ss)]
    statSim[i] <- cor(ltM1, ltM2ss)
  }
  if (graph == TRUE)
  {
    plot(1, main = "resampled data density distribution", xlim = c(0, statObs+0.1), ylim = c(0,14))
    points(density(statSim), type="l", lwd=2)
    abline(v = statObs)
    text(10, 10, "observed corelation = ")
  }
  list( obs = statObs , sumFit = sum(statSim > statObs)/numR)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're computing the correlation between the covariance matrices. When you generate the covariance matrices for the columns of `mat1`, `mat2`, and all the resampled `mat2`s, they will *all* tend to have large values on the diagonal. Thus, when you try to compute the correlation between these, there will *always* be some correlation.

I am not totally clear from your question, since it says "bootstrap" but all you do in the code is randomly permute the data *without* replacement. However, from the `sumFit` output argument in your code, it looks like you're trying to use permutation methods to calculate something like an empiric p-value (i.e. the proportion of the `statSim`s determined from the resampled `mat2`s that are more extreme than the `statObs` you got using the true data). If that is the case, then here is a simplified example using the absolute value of the correlation as the test statistic:

```js
resamplerSimAlt <- function(mat1, mat2, numR, graph = FALSE)
{  
  statObs <- abs(cor(as.vector(mat1), as.vector(mat2)))

  statSim <- replicate(numR, abs(cor(as.vector(mat1), mat2[sample(length(mat2))])))

  if (graph == TRUE)
  {
    plot(density(statSim),
      main = "resampled data density distribution",
      type = "l",
      lwd  = 2,
      xlim = c(0, max(c(statSim, statObs))))
    abline(v = statObs)
  }
  list( obs = statObs, sumFit = sum(statSim > statObs)/numR, statSim = statSim)
}
```

```
set.seed(12345)
n    <- 20
mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(n^2), n)
mat2 <- mat1 + rnorm(n^2, 0, 10)
numR <- 10000

dev.new(width=4, height=4)
results <- resamplerSimAlt(mat1, mat2, numR, graph=T)
```

```
> results[1:2]
$obs
[1] 0.1190381

$sumFit
[1] 0.0183
```

[image]

Also take a look at the `boot` package, which has a ton of related methods that can be used off-the-shelf for getting empiric confidence intervals and such.

Comment: Wow I largely overlooked the _replicate_ function but the code John suggested acts in exactly the same way as the one above. Sure there is a problem with V/CV matrices but I don`t know how to compare covariance patterns if not through V/CV matrices comparison...